# MiKTeX not hyphenating (again)

Tags: miktex, hyphenation

I have the following tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Cohesive zone model is a promising technique for simulating fracture 
processes in brittle ice. In this work it is applied to investigate the 
fracture behavior of polycrystalline cylindrical samples under uniaxial 
loading conditions, four-point beam bending, and L-shaped beam bending. In 
each case, the simulation results are compared with the corresponding 
experimental data. 
\end{document}
```

When compiled in Overleaf.com, the word "processes" hyphenates as "pro-cesses". However, when compiled with MiKTeX, there is no hyphenation. I tried the following command in Ubuntu 18.04 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050):

```
pdflatex main.tex
```

Also, I tried using the docker image (MiKTeX 2.9.6980):

```
docker run -ti -v `pwd`:/miktex/work miktex/miktex pdflatex main.tex
```

Both options yield overfilled boxes as shown on the attached image. How to enable the hyphenation? [image: (]

Comment: "Processes" is one of those words that can be hyphenated in more than one way, depending on the meaning, so ordinarily, (La)TeX wouldn't hyphenate it at all.  To be certain, I'd want to check the "chosen authoritative" dictionary (Webster's 3rd International), which is available only on paper, and then enter an explicit discretionary hyphen (`\-`) where needed,  The hyphenation `pro-cess` is suitable for "procession", but I think not for carrying out a physical process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above-mentioned versions of MikTex do not hyphenate anything. The newest version, MiKTeX 2.9.7140, seems to work fine, but it is not yet available on the official repository.

Answer (score 1):

A different docker image, 'mlevitt/miktex-basic', worked fine. Problem solved.